# Escape newline character in DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a Parquet table in Hive which I read via Spark and write to a delimited file. The code I use is this

```
var x = spark.table("myschema.my_table")
x.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").save("/tmp/abc")
```

So far, so good. But the Hive table can contain data that has `\n` in it. Now when I write the data, that character breaks the line into a new one, creating an extra broken record. The character can be there in any column. How can I set it to replace it with a space while writing? I tried the following but it didn't work

```
x.write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("multiline", "true").save("/tmp/abc")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are no such options provided by spark to replace \n with space while writing dataframe to csv. Check Aavailable options [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#csv(path:String):Unit).

You can use regex_replace to replace \n with space and then write the dataframe to CSV.

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
  import spark.implicits._
  spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

  val inDF = List(("a\nb", "c\nd", "d\ne", "ef")).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
  inDF.show()
/*
  +----+----+----+----+
  |col1|col2|col3|col4|
  +----+----+----+----+
  | a
    b| c
  d| d
  e|  ef|
    +----+----+----+----+ */

  val outDF = inDF.columns.foldLeft(inDF)((df, c) => df.withColumn(c, regexp_replace(col(c), "\n", "")))
  outDF.show()
/*
  +----+----+----+----+
  |col1|col2|col3|col4|
  +----+----+----+----+
  |  ab|  cd|  de|  ef|
  +----+----+----+----+ */

  outDF.write.option("header", true).csv("outputPath")
```